# How to filter data from SQLDataSource

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, web

I'm trying to filter the data from SQLDataSource *POSTCODE_Data* by textbox name *PostCode1*.

I do this by using the `.Rowfilter` property, but it's not working. The result, *POSTCODE_Data* is still not filtered.

What do I have to do to get the desired result?

```vb
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dv As DataView
    Dim recPostDes As String
    Dim recMiles As Integer
    dv = CType(POSTCODE_Data.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    dv.RowFilter = "POSTCODE = '" & PostCode1.Text & "%'"
    recPostDes = CType(dv.Table.Rows(0)(3), String)
    recMiles = CType(dv.Table.Rows(0)(5), Integer)
    If recMiles > 0 Then
        Des1.Text = recPostDes
        Mile1.Text = recMiles
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you're trying to create a [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) expression. If so, change `=` to `Like`

```vb
dv.RowFilter = "POSTCODE Like '" & PostCode1.Text & "%'"
```

> <sup>**DataView**
> *"Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation. The DataView does not store data, but instead represents a connected view of its corresponding DataTable. Changes to the DataView’s data will affect the DataTable. Changes to the DataTable’s data will affect all DataViews associated with it."* - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) -</sup>

Now, here's your problem: You're accessing the underlying table (`dv.Table`) and **not** the view.

```vb
recPostDes = CType(dv.Item(0).Row.Item(3), String)
recMiles = CType(dv.Item(0).Row.Item(5), Integer)
```

Or

```vb
recPostDes = CType(dv(0)(3), String)
recMiles = CType(dv(0)(5), Integer)
```